# Hangfire Recurring Jobs Break

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, hangfire

I've got a HangFire setup in a .NET Core app. I've got several recurring jobs that are set to run every 15 minutes. In the Set table, when the scheduling is working correctly, you can see the next run time in Epoch format:

[image]

However, seemingly at random, the scheduling seems to die, looking more like this instead:

[image]

As per @Satpal's suggestion, I connected the dashboard and that has shed some more light on the situation.

```
System.TypeLoadException
Could not load type 'X.API.Controllers.YController' from assembly 'X.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'X.API.Controllers.YController' from assembly 'X.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(QCallAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.TypeResolver(Assembly assembly, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveType(Assembly assembly, String[] names, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.DefaultTypeResolver(String typeName)
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
```

I know that the method being called by the recurring job is available and working currently, as manually rescheduling one of the failed jobs has worked as expected. My suspicion is the methods are unavailable when deploying updates - the period in which the app service is restarting is maybe enough for the jobs to fail, and die. I believe this is supported by a section I found in Hangfire's documentation, where it notes that:

> background processing will be stopped after 10 retry attempts with increasing delay modifier

Two questions that I have regarding this are:

1. What is the best way to be notified of job failure? A quick google seems to suggest adding logging to Hangfire and using an error log event to trigger an email? Is there a better way?
2. Is there a way to automatically retrigger recurring jobs that've been stopped due to job failure?

Thanks!

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: If you have integrated the dashboard, see if any error is logged.

Comment: @Satpal thanks for the suggestion - I did check out the dashboard and it shed some more light on the situation - see updated post.

Comment: Are you using controller action methods as job methods? Since you are getting `Could not load type 'X.API.Controllers.YController'`. I would strongly recommend doing away with the approach. Refactor your application and specific Business layer methods as scheduled jobs.

Comment: @Satpal I am using controller methods, yes. Hangfire is able to successfully execute the methods. The jobs are created like such -> RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("TaskX", () => ExecuteTask(0), "*/15 * * * *"); <- Would you have a link to a resource that explains how to do this differently? I don't understand what refactoring is required.